# 1021: Duplicate function definition in my action Script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

This is a follow up to my previous question ([Problems Scripting Multiple Buttons(nearly identical) in a single Action Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994739/problems-scripting-multiple-buttonsnearly-identical-in-a-single-action-script))

I am making an interactive flash Project...It has has 17 Separate scenes ...

- Intro Scene
- "Main_ Sequence"
- 15 Individually title song pages
  ....

Where my first issue is the "main sequence" has 15 Buttons and I need to link them to the 15 separate scenes ...I am using the following code...

```
    TD_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    s_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    ats_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    iyk_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    hms_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    tf_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    hd_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    ld_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    ll_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    ts_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    ipsy_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    ysm_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    ihm_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    iss_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    tl_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
   var nameOfButton:String=event.currentTarget.name;
   if (nameOfButton=="TD_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "Tweedlee_Dee");
} else if (nameOfButton=="s_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "Sincerely");
} else if (nameOfButton=="ats_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "Ain’_that_a_shame");
} else if (nameOfButton=="iyk_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "I_hear_you_knocking");
} else if (nameOfButton=="hms_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "Hearts_made_of_stone");
} else if (nameOfButton=="tf_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "Tutti_fruiti");
} else if (nameOfButton=="hd_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "Hound_Dog");
} else if (nameOfButton=="ld_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "Little_darlin");
} else if (nameOfButton=="ll_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "Louie_Louie");
} else if (nameOfButton=="ts_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "Twist_and_shout");
} else if (nameOfButton=="ipsy_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "I_put_a_spell_on_you");
} else if (nameOfButton=="ysm_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "You_shook_me");

} else if (nameOfButton=="ihm_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "I_can_hear_music");

} else if (nameOfButton=="iss_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "I_shot_the_sheriff");

} else if (nameOfButton=="tl_g") {
    gotoAndStop(1, "Tainted_love");
}
    }
```

when I run the sequence I get the following 15 errors All `1021: Duplicate function definition. Source : function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {`

I tried changing the `..._g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);`to include a unique #next to each DownHandler  ex) `TD_g.addEventListener12(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler1);`..I still get 15 errors...

Thanks !

P.S ...I am also looking to insert `stop();` somewhere in that action script so that after the animation is played for this scene people have the opportunity  to navigate and click the buttons instead of it "jumping" to the next scene!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I prefer using hash map/Dictionary to handle name/value pairs like these.
So your code could be written as:

```
var buttonMap:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
buttonMap["TD_g"] = "Tweedlee_Dee";
buttonMap["s_g"] = "Sincerely";
buttonMap["ats_g"] = "Ain’_that_a_shame";
buttonMap["iyk_g"] = "I_hear_you_knocking";
buttonMap["hms_g"] = "Hearts_made_of_stone";
buttonMap["tf_g"] = "Tutti_fruiti";
buttonMap["hd_g"] = "Hound_Dog";
buttonMap["ld_g"] = "Little_darlin";
buttonMap["ll_g"] = "Louie_Louie";
buttonMap["ts_g"] = "Twist_and_shout";
buttonMap["ipsy_g"] = "I_put_a_spell_on_you";
buttonMap["ysm_g"] = "You_shook_me";
buttonMap["ihm_g"] = "I_can_hear_music";
buttonMap["iss_g"] = "I_shot_the_sheriff";
buttonMap["tl_g"] = "Tainted_love";

TD_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
s_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
ats_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
iyk_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
hms_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
tf_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
hd_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
ld_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
ll_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
ts_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
ipsy_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
ysm_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
ihm_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
iss_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
tl_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(1, buttonMap[event.currentTarget.name]);
}
```

Still that doesn't solve your problem. The error says you have `function mouseDownHandler` defined somewhere else in your code. Click on the lines with the errors in compiler errors and find the duplicate code. Comment it for now then figure out why it was copy/pasted in the first place and improve/fix that. HTH

Comment: ok I figure it out ...I have 15 separate scenes (one for each song) and they all have 1 button that has the following code `stop();
"UniqueInstace".addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseDownHandler);
function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {

 gotoAndStop(525,"Main_Sequence");
}` those are supposed to send people back to the point in the main sequence where the animation has finished playing and people can click to go visit the individual pages...this is no longer working and obviously needs to be changed on each of the individual scene  action script pages ???

Comment: @user2278533 looks like you copy/pasted the code from one frame to all the other and changed the instance names,but left the handler function with the same name which isn't allowed in actionscript. You've got multiple options:1.keep it dirty and have individual listeners for each button,but at least change the handler:`TD_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, TD_gMouseDownHandler);function TD_gMouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{Tweedlee_Dee}` then `s_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, s_gMouseDownHandler);function s_gMouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{gotoAndStop(1,"Sincerely");}`

Comment: @user2278533 2. have all the button instances available in all the frames, although they are in the view/clickable only on the frames they need (this way you won't get null object references when you add listeners) and you can set all the mouse handlers in one go in one frame like the code above. 3. similar to 2, but if you don't want to make the instances available on all frames, use an event hander for Event.RENDER and use stage.invalidate()...plenty of [posts](http://richardleggett.co.uk/blog/2008/02/18/enabling_access_to_timeline_items_in_as3/) on the technique,but not as easy as 2 for you

Comment: I was not very clear ..I have separate instance names for the "Home" buttons so the code for each page now looks like ...`stop();
td_home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,td_homemouseDownHandler);
function td_homemouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {

 gotoAndStop(525,"Main_Sequence");
}
`  Everything appears to work fine no compiler code errors however(see next comment)

Comment: when I go to "test the movie" it takes forever to load(sometimes wont..) & when it does work  plays the first scene as normal then when it gets to the "main sequence" it starts the first part of the animation then frezess with the following error TypeError: **Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
  at music_Sheet_project_15_fla::MainTimeline/frame91()** ..what Should I be looking for at frame 91 ?

Comment: I cant verify if the buttons from the main sequence to the song pages work or vice versa because it wont finish loading the main animation ...

Comment: **This Project is due Tuesday Am :( & I have to give a functional presentation @ 9:30Am tmmrw right after an exam :( **

Comment: It sound like a very messy project and unless it's yours should steer away from. My answer is helpful for the issue listed above. the null object reference is a common error u can lookup, but mainly means you have code that is trying to access an object that is no longer there or doesn't exist yet. try to comment code on frame 91 to isolate the issue, then gradually comment stuff back ti find the culprit. who knows what other mess awaits though next. fact that it takes ages to compile probably means assets aren't optimised(mess). generate a size report(look it up) and work from there. goodluck

Comment: Update ...I have check all the layers ...Theres nothing on frame 91 other then being in the middle two tweens for ain't that a shame...http://s22.postimg.org/qdoja6xnl/Untitled_picture3.png

Comment: There's not supposed to be any code on that frame anywhere ?... is there way to search all the layers ?

Comment: when I run debug it gives Frame91:18 ..what is the 18 in reference to ?

Comment: is that in the MainTimeline (main/original scene) ?

Comment: the screen shot ?   it was in the debug window that the frame 91:18 appeared ...yes!

Comment: ..the Only Action script in the entire file is what you helped me with on its own layer at the top of the main scene and the snippits on there own layers in each of the other scenes

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at music_Sheet_project_15_fla::MainTimeline/frame91()[music_Sheet_project_15_fla.MainTimeline::frame91:18]

Comment: hmmm...might have been me: have u copied this as is: `function TD_gMouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{Tweedlee_Dee} ` should be `function TD_gMouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{gotoAndStop(1,"Tweedlee_Dee");} `, if so, my bad, it's 1:40 here, gonna sleep :) always test and be careful when copy/pasting :D

Comment: oh and uncompressed its 38.3814mb

Comment: I really Appreciate your help ...I will retry it

Comment: ..well no luck.that code was for the individual pages but the compiler says the problems on the main page...I will follow this up as a new question for the community Many thanks !!!