# Error #1009 .....(done some research still no solution !)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

So this is the continuation of a project ...[1021: Duplicate function definition in my action Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000556/1021-duplicate-function-definition-in-my-action-script)

I am making an interactive flash Project...It has has 17 Separate scenes ...

Intro Scene
"Main_ Sequence"
15 Individually title song pages ....

The Intro Scene Plays and then by defualt(without coding) jumps to the "Main_ Sequence"..

In the "Main_Sequence" there is an animation that is supposed to play out (was working fine prior) and then the entire sequence is supposed to "stop" once its fished (not sure where to implement`stop();` so it does not go to the next scene)

then when you mouse over every musical note on the screen it has a mouse over effect....when you click the song titles your supposed to "jump" to the particular scene labeled for that song which in turn has a home button to bring you back ...

Thanks to @George Profenza for helping me get the code for the buttons to work(?) ...I say (?) because when I go to test the movie it loads up and plays the intro ...jumps to the main sequence and then plays the first two parts of the animation and then freezes with the following ouput error **TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at music_Sheet_project_15_fla::MainTimeline/frame91()[music_Sheet_project_15_fla.MainTimeline::frame91:18]**

I understand the following about 1009's
 it mainly means there is  code that is trying to access an object that is no longer there or doesn't exist yet....The only problem with this being that I have nothing other then two motion tweens at the frame ....and no reference in my action code to the 91 frame/no code on those layers .....http://s22.postimg.org/qdoja6xnl/Untitled_picture3.png the first frame where I need to access the buttons(song titles is after all the animations have loaded ie frame#525)

...And finally the code for that Main scene

```
  var buttonMap:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
  buttonMap["TD_g"] = "Tweedlee_Dee";
  buttonMap["s_g"] = "Sincerely";
  buttonMap["ats_g"] = "Ain’_that_a_shame";
  buttonMap["iyk_g"] = "I_hear_you_knocking";
  buttonMap["hms_g"] = "Hearts_made_of_stone";
  buttonMap["tf_g"] = "Tutti_fruiti";
  buttonMap["hd_g"] = "Hound_Dog";
  buttonMap["ld_g"] = "Little_darlin";
  buttonMap["ll_g"] = "Louie_Louie";
  buttonMap["ts_g"] = "Twist_and_shout";
  buttonMap["ipsy_g"] = "I_put_a_spell_on_you";
  buttonMap["ysm_g"] = "You_shook_me";
  buttonMap["ihm_g"] = "I_can_hear_music";
  buttonMap["iss_g"] = "I_shot_the_sheriff";
  buttonMap["tl_g"] = "Tainted_love";

  TD_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
  s_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
  ats_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
  iyk_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
  hms_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
  tf_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
 hd_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
 ld_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
 ll_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
 ts_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
 ipsy_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
 ysm_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
 ihm_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
 iss_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
 tl_g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
gotoAndStop(1, buttonMap[event.currentTarget.name]);
}
```

Is it possible that the error is caused because the song title buttons are bitmaps and only become "buttons" @Frame 525 ..if this is the case why would it not give the error for the first two songtitles that also only become buttons@Frame525?

If I cant get past the output error I cant test the functionality of the buttons..Some Help /Advice would be greatly appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

So It would appear that by placing the action script at frame 525 in its own layer rather then Placing it @Frame 1 in its layer...the problem is now solved....However 5 out of the 30 buttons are not functioning which I will troubleshoot....The Take away from this is that the location of your Actionscript in the timeline is critical !

Comment: Yes, if a script references an object that doesn't exist when the script runs, you will indeed get that error.